# How to grep a pattern followed by a number, only if the number is above a certain value

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I actually need to grep the entire line. I have a file with a bunch of lines that look like this

```
1  123213 A T . stuff=1.232;otherstuf=34;morestuff=121;AF=0.44;laststuff=AV
4  223152 D L . stuff=1.122;otherstuf=4;morestuff=41;AF=0.02;laststuff=RV
```

and I want to keep all the lines where AF>0.1. So for the lines above I only want to keep the first line.

Comment: Do you know that `AF` is always of the form `0.NN`? If not you should parse the fields and compare the value as a number, rather than try to use regular expressions.

Comment: no it is not a consistent number of digits. There could be AF=1 or AF =0.00054435.   I was hoping to avoid splitting it, but oh well. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with extracting the field (and it won't even necessarily be less efficient), and it's far more correct to do arithmetic than string matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` with multiple delimeters to extract the value and compare it:

`$ awk -F';|=' '$8 > 0.1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Using gnu-awk you can do this:

```
awk 'gensub(/.*;AF=([^;]+).*/, "\\1", "1", $NF)+0 > 0.1' file

1  123213 A T . stuff=1.232;otherstuf=34;morestuff=121;AF=0.44;laststuff=AV
```

This `gensub` function parses out `AF=<number>` from last field of the input and captures number in captured group #1 which is used for comparison with `0.1`.

PS: `+0` will convert parsed field to a number.

Comment: @AkshayHegde using a substitution function i.e. `gensub` means this is slower than the other solutions.

Comment: Slower/Faster is not the issue. As per OP requirement is to match `AF>0.1` condition, which may or not be at given filed position.

Comment: @anubhava based on the fact the OP replied to another field based answer  saying it worked, i would assume the field position is fixed.

Comment: @Zlemini : Question was how to grep pattern followed by  number and then to check whether its within some value, for that anubhava's solution suits the best among all here, what if `AF` followed by number is somewhere in 2nd or 5th field for the said separator with `-F` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `AF` is always of the form `0.NN` you can simply match values where the tens place is 1-9, e.g.:

```
grep ';AF=0.[1-9][0-9];' your_file.csv
```

You could add a `+` after the second character group to support additional digits (i.e. `0.NNNNN`) but if the values could be outside the range [0, 1) you shouldn't try to match the field with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F= '$5>0.1' file
1  123213 A T . stuff=1.232;otherstuf=34;morestuff=121;AF=0.44;laststuff=AV
```

If that doesn't do what you want when run against your real data then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk`. Since `awk` supports alphanumerical comparisons you can simply use this:

```
awk -F';' '$(NF-1) > "AF=0.1"' file.txt
```

`-F';'` splits the line into fields by `;`. `$(NF-1)` address the second last field in the line. (`NF` is the number of fields)

Comment: That won't find a record if input line is `1  123213 A T . stuff=1.232;otherstuf=34;morestuff=121;AF=.44;laststuff=AV`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, this is not a numeric comparison. I've used it since it looks like `AF` is always in format `x.xx`. Probably [Zlemini's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41469627/171318) is the best here. It is the shortest and still performs a numerical comparison.

Comment: Yes, that answer is shortest but assumes `AF` field is field #8 but OP just asks for `AF>0.1` condition.